# Python: How do I put print statement and input on same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make it that when the user enters input its on the same line as the print statement

like for example for the code snippet below. The output becomes:

```
Enter grade for course 1: A
Enter credits for course 1: 4
```

For now this is what I get:

```
Enter grade for course 1: 
A
Enter credits for course 1:
4
```

Here is the code snippet

```
for i in range(1,coursenumber+1):
    print("Enter grade for course ", i,":", end =""),
    grade=str(input())
    print("Enter credits for course", i,":", end =" ")
    credit=int(input())
    totalgpa+=translate(credit,grade)
    totalcredit+=credit
```

Comment: Sorry guys. I made edits. I think it is clear now

Comment: How are you running your code? I ask because one of the ways I tested it (in an iPython console in Spyder) it prints the way you say it does, but when I run it from a normal console it works as you intended.

Comment: There is a comma in the second line.

Comment: @Blckknght am using Spyder. I got the solution from the answers below.

Comment: Yep, that's an issue with the iPython console, not really with your code (though the code *can* be improved).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write the question inside the input function like

```
for i in range(1,coursenumber+1):
    grade=input(f"Enter grade for course {i}:")
    credit=input(f"Enter credits for course {i}:")
    totalgpa+=translate(credit,grade)
    totalcredit+=credit
```

Then the input prompt appears right next to the question

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `print()` first, use just `input()` like this:

```
question="Enter grade for course" + str(i)
grade=input(question)
```

`question` can be whatever, you just can't combine strings inside the `input()` function.

Comment: That doesn't work. The argument to `input` needs to be a single string, but your `question` variable is a 3-tuple. You probably need to do some string formatting to get it to work.

Comment: I agree with Blckknght. You can do something like: `question="Enter grade for course"+str(i)+ ": "`

Comment: @BlackThunder Yes, realized that. Oops. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize cursor movements to be able to print and take input on the same line. This will allow you to take to inputs on the same line as well.

```py
main.py
-------
print("something")
res = input("\033[1A \033[9C Write something here:")
            
            #\033[<num>A -> move cursor up 'num' lines
            #\033[<num>C -> move cursor up 'num' columns

output
------
> somethingWrite something here:▒
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have now should work. If it does not, it's because you're not using a normal console for output. That said, as other answers have suggested, you can do better by including the prompt in the call to `input`, rather than in a separate `print` call.

The only complication is that you need to format the prompt yourself, rather than passing separate arguments, like you can do with `print`. Fortunately, string formatting isn't to hard. I'd do something like this:

```
input("Enter grade for course {}: ".format(i))
```