# Python 3 - How can I use "input" without a new line after typing ENTER?

Tags: python-3.x, input

in the terminal I want to use `input` without a new line, to do that I tried to code something like that:

```
psw=input('Type the password and press "ENTER": ')
print(" [OK]", end="\n")
```

unfortunately it didn't work, after typing ENETER, the input function prints always a new line. how can I avoid this behavior? the option `end=""` used in the `print` function here doesn't exist.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69001565/188331)

Comment: @Raptor it does not solve the question. The OP doesn’t want a new line each time input is entered.